# Switching from min-heap to max-heap without rearrange the internal array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we have a *min heap* with some elements which satisfy the heap property.
What happens if I change the algorithm from min heap to *max heap* without rearrange the internal array?

That is, if I keep the array unchanged, what happens when I append an element to the internal array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap):
[image]

The array representation of this would look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 17, 19, 36, 7, 25, 100]
```

Now we "change" the heap from min to max, but without rearranging the elements and insert a new element "25". The array position would be 9 so the parent node is "19" at position 4.

After inserting we must repeatedly compare the new item with its parent to ensure heap property (now max-heap => parent must be greater than child). Thus we must swap "25" with "19", "2" and "1" until it is the root node.

Now the max-heap property holds for the root node (its children are indeed smaller), but not for the other nodes, e.g. "3" is still the parent of "7" and violates the max-heap condition.

To conclude this: Doing what you describe does not change the min-heap to a max-heap.

Answer (score 6):

You would just screw the heap.

You have to re-heapify (this can be done in time O(N)).