# java heapify method with comparator

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I am trying to write a class `HeapQueue`. I stored left child of root at  `2 * indexOfRoot + 1` index, and right child at `2 * indexOfRoot + 2`.

```
public class HeapQueue implements PriorityQueue, BinaryHeap {

public List<Task> queue;
public Comparator comparator;

public HeapQueue() {
    queue = new ArrayList();
}

public void setComparator(Comparator comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
    heapify(0);
}

public Comparator getComparator() {
    return comparator;
}

public void offer(Task task) {
    int currentElement, previousElement;
    queue.add(task);
    currentElement = queue.size() - 1;
    previousElement = (currentElement - 1) / 2;
    while (previousElement >= 0 && 
             getComparator().compare(queue.get(currentElement), queue.get(previousElement)) > 0) {
        swap(currentElement, previousElement);
        currentElement = previousElement;
        previousElement = (currentElement - 1) / 2;
    }
}

private void swap(int i, int j) {
    Task t1 = queue.get(i);
    Task t2 = queue.get(j);
    Task t3 = t1;
    queue.set(i, t2);
    queue.set(j, t3);
}
}
```

Queue storaged object of `Task`.

```
public class Task {

private final String name;
private final int priority;

public Task(String name, int priority) {
    this.name = name;
    this.priority = priority;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + "\tpriority = " + priority;
}
}
```

I have a method `heapify()` in `HeapQueue`:

```
public void heapify(int root) {
    int leftChild, rightChild;
    leftChild = 2 * root + 1;
    if (leftChild < queue.size()) {
        rightChild = leftChild + 1;
        if ((rightChild < queue.size())
                && getComparator().compare(queue.get(rightChild), queue.get(leftChild)) > 0) {
            leftChild = rightChild;
        }
        if (getComparator().compare(queue.get(leftChild), queue.get(root)) > 0) {
            swap(root, leftChild);
            heapify(leftChild);
        }
    }

}
```

By my task comparator may be changed by method `setComparator()` after adding task to queue.
Default `Comparator` is:

```
public class Comparator{
    public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
        if (t1.getPriority() == t2.getPriority()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (t1.getPriority() < t2.getPriority()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } //sorting max
    }
 }
```

As example other comparator may be:

```
public class otherComparator{
    public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
        if (t1.getPriority() == t2.getPriority()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (t1.getPriority() < t2.getPriority()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1; 
        } //sorting min
    }
 }
```

I create my `HeapQueue` and add some elements.

```
HeapQueue heap = new HeapQueue();
heap.setComparator(comparator);
Task t1 = new Task("a", 1);
Task t2 = new Task("b", 2);
Task t3 = new Task("c", 3);
Task t4 = new Task("d", 4);
System.out.println(heap.queue.toString());
```

Result is:

```
[d priority = 4, c  priority = 3, b priority = 2, a priority = 1]

    4
   / \
  3   2
 /
1
```

It's right. But when I change `Comparator` to `otherComparator`:

```
otherComparator newComparator = new otherComparator();
heap.setComparator(newComparator);
System.out.println(heap.queue.toString());
```

Result is:

```
[b priority = 2, c  priority = 3, d priority = 4, a priority = 1]

    2
   / \
  3   4
 /
1
```

It's wrong. Right answer is something like this:

```
[a priority = 1, b priority = 2, c  priority = 3, d priority = 4]

    1
   / \
  2   3
 /
4
```

I think I have a problem with `heapify()` function. But I cannot find a mistake. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you share your swap function too?

Comment: @PhamTung It's there.

Comment: Hmm how can you set `otherComparator` as Comparator for the heap? it is not implementing same interface?

Comment: @PhamTrung By the task comparator for the heap can be changed, and by setComparator(), I can change comparator and re-build heap by heapify(). But it don't work.

Comment: I see, ok, I can reproduce the bug now :)

Comment: Your fix runs in O(n log n). Look at the reheapify answer I give. It runs in O(n). Basically, if you build your tree in bulk instead of node by node, you can reduce the time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solve problem by creating function `rebuild()`:

```
private void rebuild() {
    HeapQueue reHeap = new HeapQueue();
    reHeap.setComparator(comparator);
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        reHeap.offer(queue.get(i));
    }
    queue = reHeap.queue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just change from **max heap to min heap**, which broken whole heap structure!.

The problem is, when you change the comparator, calling `heapify(0)` is not enough, because, for example, this structure:

```
             4
            / \
           3   2
          /
         1
```

After `heapify`, 1 will not move up, because after `heapify(0)`, the program jump to the **right child**, which is 2 and from that we cannot reach 1.

You can just create another heap!

You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286237/switching-from-min-heap-to-max-heap-without-rearrange-the-internal-array), basically, when changing the comparator, you just broke the heap structure!

Comment: @AlexeySharov yes, the reason is, my tree structure is different, so it luckily run correctly, but `heapify(0)` is not enough, as I pointed above!

Comment: If you do this: `heap.offer(t1);` `heap.offer(t2);` `heap.offer(t3);` `heap.offer(t4);` You will have my problem. I cannot forget to heapify because I have `heapify()` in `setComparator()`.

Comment: Why `heapify(0)` in `setComparator()` isn't enough? It have to be enough.

Comment: @AlexeySharov, no, calm down man :), just reread my explanation, as heapify is based on the fact that the structure in the heap is correct, but in this heap, when you change from max to min heap, all condition is violated, so you cannot count on heapify any more.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286237/switching-from-min-heap-to-max-heap-without-rearrange-the-internal-array) isn't my question.  
"That is, if I keep the array unchanged, what happens when I append an element to the internal array?"
But I want to change my heap after changing comparator and adding new element.

Comment: @AlexeySharov hmm, do you agree that after swap the comparator, whole structure of the max heap is not changed, and calling heapify only change one part of the heap, not the whole heap. When you compare, you only compare with two nearest children, which is not correct!.

Comment: OK. But have a automatic testing system. And my code don't passing this test:
checkComparatorChangeAfterAddingTasks [ FAILED ] 
Checking whether output is ordered (ascending) and there is a task with lower priority than the previous one

Comment: So, I think solution must exist.

Comment: @AlexeySharov I cannot understand your point, please provide more background info :), yes, there exists an solution, but with work, you need to restructure the whole thing, so you may need to remove and re add all element again.

Comment: I have task at university, it's too long to write whole task here, but most of the information required above. Than I have a system of checking tasks with some tests. I cannot pass test, named "checkComparatorChangeAfterAddingTask".

Comment: `heapify()` have to keep on heap property

Answer (score 1):

You need to do more than just heapify down (as you have in heapify -- pushing a node down the tree) or heapify up (as you have in the offer method -- pulling a node up the tree). Those will only work to fix up a single node on removal or addition respectively. The rest of the heap has to already abide by the heap rule.

You need to entirely reheapify the structure. This can be done in linear time by starting at the bottom of the structure and pushing down each root to the correct subtree. Think of it like running heapify down for each node with children starting at the tail/end of the complete tree.

```
rehapify arraynodes:
    for i from arraynodes.length / 2:
      heapifydown( arraynodes, i )
```

Where heapifydown is your heapify function.

Comment: For each `heapifyDown`, I see that it needs to travel O(log n) from top to bottom, which basically is O(nlogn), however, this is not a  tight bound, can you provide a mathematical prove that this is O(n)?

Comment: Your time complexity is log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log 1 = log(n*(n-1)*(n-2)...) = log(n!) ~ O(n log n). More [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: It only looks that way,  but each pass orders the tree more and more.  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-85/